# vbNewLine does not reflect until double click?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some cells that I merge through my code,

```
If InStr(outSht.Cells(lRow2, 3), entry.Offset(, 1)) = 1 Then 'does name exist?
            outSht.Cells(lRow2, 4) = outSht.Cells(lRow2, 4) & vbNewLine & entry.Offset(, 1)
        End If
        outSht.Cells(lRow2, 6) = outSht.Cells(lRow2, 6) & vbNewLine & entry.Offset(, -2)
        outSht.Cells(lRow2, 7) = outSht.Cells(lRow2, 7) + entry.Offset(, 2)
```

However, it ends up all on the same line until I doubleclick the cell manually. Here is a quick gif that shows what is going on.

https://gyazo.com/eb50d0ecb25e022b53643a65917ac835

Am I missing something very basic? I tried `Chr(10)`, `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`, and `vbCrLf` to no avail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue you had and something similar worked when using the symbol with ACSII 13. When using a character with ASCII 10, everything works correctly. **Try forcing the `.WrapText = True` property**. Below is the test code to investigate the problem:

```
Sub test1()
    a = Array(vbLf, vbCr, vbCrLf, vbNewLine, Chr(10), Chr(13))
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete    ' clear the Worksheet
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        For i = 0 To UBound(a)
            txt = ""
            For s = 1 To Len(a(i))
                txt = txt & "," & Asc(Mid(a(i), s, 1))
            Next
            txt = Mid(txt, 2)
            
            .Offset(i).WrapText = False
            .Offset(i).Value = "A1-101222" & a(i) & "A1-103209" & a(i) & "A1-101406"
            .Offset(i, 1).Value = "Used " & i & " symbol(s) ASCII[" & txt _
                & "] and final WrapText is: " & .Offset(i).WrapText
        Next
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

> Output
> [image]